# How to remove duplicates from set of machine precision 2D points?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, numerics

I have a set of 2D points with machine precision coordinates. I need to remove all duplicates. Performance is important.

This is the most obvious fast solution:

```
Union[points]
```

Unfortunately it turns out that unlike `Equal` and `SameQ`, `Union` has no tolerance for any difference with machine precision numbers, which makes it unusable for this purpose.

```
In[1]:= 
a = 1.;
b = a + $MachineEpsilon;

In[3]:= a == b
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= a === b
Out[4]= True

In[5]:= Union[{a, b}]
Out[5]= {1., 1.}
```

Using the `SameTest` option of `Union` works, but it is not a good option because it makes the complexity $n^2$.

So what is the fastest way to get rid of duplicates while allowing for a tolerance of comparisons, and preferably being able to control it (`` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``, `` Internal`$SameQTolerance ``)?

Comment: A single argument `DeleteDuplicates` seems faster than single argument `Union` here

Comment: @Rojo For a list of what size with how many duplicates?

Comment: For the same test data of your answer. `Union` takes about 7 seconds and `DeleteDuplicates` slightly less than 3. So, 10000000 length and 3677844 duplicates this time

Comment: Would you mind adding the test case in the question? For me, `DeleteDuplicates` is usually the fastest solution. There are some threads on mathgroup why this should be so, too...

Comment: @Szabolcs a random comment - congratulations on getting the 1337th `nice question` badge! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another compiled implementation. It's only very slightly faster than the [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22090) of [s0rce](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/65), which is due to this version making only one array access (rather than two) per inner loop iteration. It also uses the `` Internal`Bag ``, which may be advantageous for memory consumption in case there are many duplicates.

It must be said that this is still not as fast as `Union`, but at least it acknowledges `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` while being faster than `Split`. The value of `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` is actually hard-coded into the bytecode on compilation, so it will be necessary to recompile if a different tolerance is required.

```
compiledUnion = Compile[{{r, _Real, 2}},
   Block[{
     sorted = Sort[r], output,
     seen, current
    },
    output = Internal`Bag[seen = First[sorted], 1];
    Do[
     If[i != seen, Internal`StuffBag[output, seen = i, 1]],
     {i, sorted}
    ];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[output, All], Length[seen]]
   ],
   RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "CompareWithTolerance" -> True},
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];
```

Test case, with the default value of `` Internal`$EqualTolerance == 7 Log[2]/Log[10] ``:

```
compiledUnion[{
  {1., 1., 1.}, {1. + $MachineEpsilon, 1., 1.}, {1., 1. + $MachineEpsilon, 1.},
  {2., 1., 1.}
 }]
(* -> {{1., 1., 1.}, {2., 1., 1.}} *)
```

Performance comparison, in ascending order of run-time:

```
r = RandomReal[1, {10000000, 2}];
r = RandomChoice[r, 10000000];

DeleteDuplicates[r]; (* 1.813 seconds; incorrect result (no tolerance) *)
DeleteDuplicates[r, Equal]; (* same timing and result--incorrect special-casing *)
Sort[r]; (* 4.297 seconds; base case for Union-like approaches *)
Union[r]; (* 4.609 seconds; incorrect result (no tolerance) *)

compiledUnion[r]; (* 5.875 seconds *)
With[{sorted = Sort[r]}, Pick[sorted, deleteDuplicatesC[sorted], 1]]; (* 6.109 seconds *)

Split[Sort[r]][[All, 1]]; (* 11.953 seconds; unpacks + additional memory overhead *)
DeleteDuplicates[r, Equal[##] &]; (* 294.8 days; unpacks *)
```

Comment: Also including the `DeleteDuplicates` timing would be great.

Comment: @YvesKlett okay, I will add it later. However, it should be noted that `DeleteDuplicates`, while faster, does not actually produce the correct result.

Comment: Oleksandr, any info on that would also be welcome. I did a run that matched the result of `Union` (after being sorted).

Comment: @YvesKlett the documentation states that `DeleteDuplicates` uses `SameQ` as the default comparison function. This is not correct because `1.` is `SameQ` with `1. + $MachineEpsilon`, but `DeleteDuplicates` does not consider these as duplicates. One can give a comparison function explicitly to avoid the problem but this changes the time complexity of `DeleteDuplicates` to something like $O(N^2)$. The main point of the question is to incorporate the tolerance without destroying the reasonable scaling of `Union`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - useful info and quite subtle nuances. Perhaps @Szabolcs could add this summary to the question to fend off unqualified attempts to propose `DeleteDuplicates`. In fact `DeleteDuplicates[{1., 1. + $MachineEpsilon}, SameQ]` evaluates to `False` which is incorrect.

Comment: @YvesKlett yes--contrast e.g. `DeleteDuplicates[{1., 1. + $MachineEpsilon}, SameQ[##] &]`. From this we can see that `SameQ` is special-cased internally by `DeleteDuplicates`, but not correctly so.

Comment: @YvesKlett I added the `DeleteDuplicates` timings. I couldn't be bothered to wait for 9 months for the last one to finish, so that's an extrapolation.

Comment: How did you measure a timing of 294.8 days in a question asked yesterday? (:

Answer (score 11):

One possible solution is using `Split`, which obeys `` Internal`$SameQTolerance ``

```
r = RandomReal[1, {10000000, 2}];
r = RandomChoice[r, 10000000];

Split[Sort[r]][[All, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {12.756712, Null} *)
```

This is about 3-4 times slower than `Union`:

```
Union[r]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {4.306363, Null} *)
```

Comment: Since `Split` only compares adjacent elements, it is not obvious to me that one iteration will always be enough. You may need something like `FixedPoint[Split[#][[All,1]]&,Sort[r]]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin If I have `{a,b,c,d,e}` and `a == b`and `b==c`, then `Split`  will give `{{a,b,c}, ...}`, so it should be fine.  The problem could be that it removes a bit too much because comparison with tolerance is not transitive, so it's possible that `a==b` and `b==c` but `a != c`.

Comment: Actually, yes, I meant this non-transitivity, but did not make the right conclusion.

Comment: I might not get it, but for this one `DeleteDuplicates` is about 2.5 times faster than `Union`...

Comment: @Szabolcs, `Split` has the disadvantage that it unpacks and thus needs more memory. Why exactly can you not use `DeleteDuplicates`? Seems faster.

Answer (score 10):

How about a compiled solution. I think this solves the transitivity issues with `Split`.

```
deleteDuplicatesC = 
  Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{i, len = Length[v], output = Table[1, {i, len}]},
    Do[If[Compile`GetElement[v, i] == Compile`GetElement[v, i - 1], 
      output[[i]] = 0], {i, 2, len}];
    output], 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "CompareWithTolerance" -> True}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

r = RandomReal[1, {10000000, 2}];
r = RandomChoice[r, 10000000];

selected = 
   With[{sorted = Sort[r]}, 
    Pick[sorted, deleteDuplicatesC[sorted], 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {4.033231, Null} *)
```

Looks like it works:

```
a = 1.;
b = a + $MachineEpsilon;
test = {{a, a}, {b, b}, {b, a}, {a, b}};
Pick[test, deleteDuplicatesC[test], 1]

(* {{1., 1.}} *)
```

Comment: Compiled `Equal` is a call to ``Internal`CompareNumeric``. The tolerance is ``$Internal`EqualTolerance`` (7 bits) if `RuntimeOptions -> "CompareWithTolerance" -> True` is set and zero otherwise. It seems like it would be possible to set the tolerance explicitly either by changing ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` before compiling the code or by editing the compiled bytecode directly. Note that you **must** manually set `"CompareWithTolerance" -> True` here because the default for `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`  is `"CompareWithTolerance" -> False`!

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR. Once you posted your first comment I found in the docs that I couldn't specify `"Speed"` think this works for the example given now.

Comment: You actually can specify `RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "CompareWithTolerance" -> True}`, FWIW.

Answer (score 4):

`Tally` also obeys `` Internal`$SameQTolerance ``:

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100000];

Tally[a][[All, 1]] // Length
```

> ```
> 100000
> ```

```
Internal`$SameQTolerance = 12.0;
Tally[a][[All, 1]] // Length
```

> ```
> 33818
> ```

I have used this to handle such problems in the past, but be aware that there remains a kind of [instability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6166895/618728).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different approach that I would find acceptable in many situations in which numbers within a certain radius or tolerance are to be considered equal.  Divide the number line up into bins of a width relative to the power of 2 of the location on the number line, and pick a representative from each bin.  The boundary cases at powers of 2 can be a problem ***if*** they are important.  I doubt they are in many applications.  Similarly if the data contain `0.`, which is not a power of 2, problems might arise.  This approach is basically what floating-point numbers do anyway, each number being a representative of a bin of relative radius `$MachineEpsilon/2`.  To semi-emulate `Equal`, the idea would be to round off the lowest seven bits.

One way to do it is to use `Round`, and another way to round off an integral number of bits is to add and subtract from a number `x` the value `` 10.^Internal`$EqualTolerance * $MachineEpsilon/2 * x ``.

```
SeedRandom[0];
r = RandomReal[{1.9999999997, 2.0000000003}, {10000000, 2}]

Block[{basetol = 10.^Internal`$EqualTolerance*$MachineEpsilon/2}, 
 DeleteDuplicates@Round[r,
     Clip[   (* $MinMachineNumber is a dodge to handle extremely small numbers and 0. *)
      basetol*(2.^Floor@Log2[$MinMachineNumber + Abs@r]),
      {$MinMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}
      ]
     ] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
 ]
(*  {3.31892, {9936697, 2}}  *)

(* assumes tolerance is an integral number of bits *)
Block[{tol = Internal`$EqualTolerance/Log10[2] - 1 // Round, shift},
  shift = 2.^(tol + Floor@Log2[$MinMachineNumber + Abs@r]);
  DeleteDuplicates@ ((r + shift) - shift)
  ] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.1248, {9936776, 2}}  *)
```

Compared to a straight `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[r] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.54819, {9999992, 2}}  *)
```

Well, the two methods are not too bad compared to the presumptive optimum of `DeleteDuplicates`.

The difference in outcomes of the two methods is explained by rounding error in second argument to `Round`:

```
(* assumes tolerance is an integral number of bits *)
Block[{basetol = Log2[10.^Internal`$EqualTolerance*$MachineEpsilon] - 1 // Round}, 
 DeleteDuplicates@Round[r,
     Clip[
      2.^(basetol + Floor@Log2[$MinMachineNumber + Abs@r]),
      {$MinMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}
      ]
     ] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
 ]
(*  {3.33764, {9936776, 2}}  *)
```

It is slightly faster not to worry about the power of `2` precisely in figuring out the `shift`, with somewhat different rounding.

```
(* assumes tolerance is an integral number of bits *)
Block[{basetol = 10.^Internal`$EqualTolerance/2 // Round, shift},
  shift = basetol*r;
  s3 = DeleteDuplicates@((r + shift) - shift);
  s3 // Dimensions
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.77393, {9937043, 2}}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that all of the other answers produce incorrect results. Consider:

```
data = {{1., 1.}, {1.+$MachineEpsilon,-1.}, {1.+$MachineEpsilon,1.}};
```

Clearly the first and last points should be considered duplicates, yet none of the other answers remove this duplicate. For example:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PrintPrecision->20];

compiledUnion[data]
Split[Sort[data]][[All, 1]]
Pick[data, deleteDuplicatesC[data], 1]
Tally[data][[All, 1]]
```

> {{1., 1.}, {1.0000000000000002, -1.}, {1.0000000000000002, 1.}}
>
> {{1., 1.}, {1.0000000000000002, -1.}, {1.0000000000000002, 1.}}
>
> {{1., 1.}, {1.0000000000000002, -1.}, {1.0000000000000002, 1.}}
>
> {{1., 1.}, {1.0000000000000002, -1.}, {1.0000000000000002, 1.}}

The other answers don't work because they basically sort and then remove adjacent duplicates. In the example above, the duplicates are not adjacent after sorting. The only suggested answer that works for this example is:

```
Union[data, SameTest->SameQ]
```

> {{1., 1.}, {1.0000000000000002, -1.}}

However, as mentioned by the OP, this method has $O(n^2)$ complexity, and moreover it uses a relative tolerance instead of an absolute tolerance. For example:

```
data2 = {{1., 1.}, {1.*^-10, 1.*^-10}, {1.*^-10+$MachineEpsilon, 1.*^-10}};
```

One might wish that the second and third points are considered duplicates, yet:

```
Union[data2, SameTest->SameQ]
```

> {{1.*10^-10, 1.*10^-10}, {1.0000022204460493*10^-10, 1.*10^-10}, {1., 1.}}

This is because the absolute difference is [`$MachineEpsilon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$MachineEpsilon), while the relative difference is only $\approx 10^{-6}$, and [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) is based on relative difference.

Here is an approach that uses absolute differences, and is orders of magnitude faster than [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) (with the [`SameTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameTest) option) for large datasets:

```
deleteDuplicatePoints[data_, tol_] := With[{n = Nearest[data->"Index", data, {All, tol}]},
    data[[DeleteDuplicates[Min/@n]]]
]
```

There are two important differences between `deleteDuplicatePoints` and [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union). First, `deleteDuplicatePoints` uses an absolute tolerance, while [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) uses a relative tolerance. Second, `deleteDuplicatePoints` uses euclidean distance, while [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) uses chessboard distance (see [`ChessboardDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChessboardDistance)).

Let's check `deleteDuplicatePoints` on our two previous examples:

```
deleteDuplicatePoints[data, $MachineEpsilon]
deleteDuplicatePoints[data2, $MachineEpsilon]
```

> {{1., 1.}, {1.0000000000000002, -1.}}
>
> {{1., 1.}, {1.*10^-10, 1.*10^-10}}

In both cases, the duplicate is removed. What about larger datasets? [`Here`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Here) is a comparison between `deleteDuplicatePoints` and [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) with a [`SameTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameTest) option for largish dataset with lots of duplicates:

```
data = RandomReal[{1, 1 + 100 $MachineEpsilon}, {10^5, 2}];
r1 = deleteDuplicatePoints[data, $MachineEpsilon];//AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Union[data, SameTest->SameQ]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.053882, Null}
>
> {1.065719, Null}

And a largish datasets with few duplicates:

```
data = RandomReal[{1, 1 + 10^5 $MachineEpsilon}, {10^4, 2}];
r1 = deleteDuplicatePoints[data, $MachineEpsilon];//AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Union[data, SameTest->SameQ]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.005078, Null}
>
> {10.17658, Null}

When there are lots of duplicates, then [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) with a [`SameTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameTest) option becomes competitive on timing because many results get pruned, and so less comparisons are needed. When there aren't a lot of duplicates, then the $O\left(n^2\right)$ behavior becomes clear. My tests indicate that the [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) approach appears to be $O(n \ln(n))$.

Finally, a speed comparison with the other answers. I will just compare `deleteDuplicatePoints` with [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) (without the [`SameTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameTest) option):

```
data = RandomReal[{1, 1 + 10^7 $MachineEpsilon}, {10^7, 2}];
r1 = deleteDuplicatePoints[data, $MachineEpsilon];//AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Union[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.612259, Null}
>
> {3.048912, Null}

So, not too much slower than [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union).

Comment: I seem to get that `deleteDuplicatePoints[r1, $MachineEpsilon]` is shorter than `r1`, and that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think you meant that `Union` removes more duplicates than `deleteDuplicatePoints` does for the largish dataset with lots of duplicates? I think this is because `Union` uses chessboard distance instead of Euclidean distance. By that I mean, with `Union` both the `x` and `y` coordinates can be off by `$MachineEpsilon`, while with `deleteDuplicatePoints` only `x` or `y` but not both can be off by $MachineEpsilon. Note that the difference between relative tolerance and absolute tolerance doesn't play much of a role because of the range I chose.

Comment: I meant iterating `deleteDuplicatePoints`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uHlTS.png  -- I guess in part it has to do with nontransitivity, but the first run seems to miss a lot?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tweaked the `Nearest` call, so that more points are pruned initially. Further work is needed, though, in determining which points can be deleted. For example, in one dimension we could have neighbors sets with indices $(1, 2)$, $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(2, 3)$. We shouldn't delete points 2 and 3, since the final set `{1}` would not be a duplicate of `3`. I'll update my answer with some thoughts on this when I get a chance.