# Multidimensional interpolation with duplicate abscissa values

Tags: interpolation

I am trying to do a first order interpolation on a multidimensional data set containing duplicate abscissa values (which Mathematica does not like), like this one:

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}
```

After playing around with DeleteDuplicates and Union I found that DeleteDuplicates does not work on multidimensional data, at least not when represented like above. I found that Union could delete the duplicates by using the SameTest-option, like this:

```
Union[{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}, SameTest -> (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &)]
```

which returns

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}
```

However, it is very slow with larger data sets, which I have, so that is not an option.

What I really would like is a function that will make an average of the duplicates, so that

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}
```

will turn into

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, 15}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}
```

I am by no means an expert in Mathematica programming, so I could really use some help.

The solution has to be reasonable fast. My data set is not sorted in any way but I guess it can be sorted quickly before the duplicates are combined if that is needed.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The first issue regarding `SameTest` has been addressed many times on this site; personally here at least:  [(17041)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17041/121),
[(21711)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21711/121),
[(28696)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28696/121),
[(30328)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30328/121).  The second part, the actual question, I believe to be yet another duplicate of [(4332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DeleteDuplicatesBy` may be faster if used as follows:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}, First]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}
> ```

For your second need:

```
lis = GatherBy[{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}, First];
mean = Mean /@ Map[Last, lis, {2}];
```

Then:

```
Transpose[{lis[[All, 1, 1]], mean}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, 15}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}
> ```

As a function:

```
delDupMean[data_] := With[{lis = GatherBy[data, First]},
  Transpose[{lis[[All, 1, 1]], Mean /@ Map[Last, lis, {2}]}]
 ]
```

Use:

```
delDupMean[{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, 15}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = {{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}};

DeleteDuplicates[lst, First@#1 == First@#2 &]
(* {{{1,2,3},10},{{1,2,4},30}} *)

First /@ GatherBy[lst, First]
(* {{{1,2,3},10},{{1,2,4},30}} *)

{#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[lst, First]
(* or {#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@Gather[lst, First@#1 == First@#2 &]  *)
(* {{{1,2,3},15},{{1,2,4},30}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an approach with `Reap` and `Sow`. Probably not be efficient.

```
data = {{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}};
Last@Reap[Sow[#2, w[#1]] & @@@data, _, {ReplacePart[#1, 0 -> Identity], Mean@#2} &]
```

yields:

```
(*{{{1, 2, 3}, 15}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lis = GatherBy[{{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}, First];

Plus @@@ lis/Length /@ lis

Plus @@ #/Length@# & /@ lis

Plus[##]/Length@{##} & @@@ lis

(*{{{1, 2, 3}, 15}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{1, 2, 3}, 10}, {{1, 2, 3}, 20}, {{1, 2, 4}, 30}};

result = GroupBy[list, First -> Last, Mean]
```

[image]

```
Normal @ result /. Rule -> List
```

[image]

**OR**

```
Thread[{Keys @ #, Mean /@ Values @ #}] &[GroupBy[list, First -> Last]]
```

[image]