# The conflated two uses of SameTest within Intersection

Tags: list-manipulation

Intersection works as expected in this case...

```
a = Range[1,5];b=Range[3,7]; Intersection[a,b]
```

giving...

```
{3,4,5}
```

However if I expand the concept of sameness using SameTest to this...

```
Intersection[a,b, SameTest->(Abs[#1-#2]<=1&)]
```

I get the slightly puzzling result of...

```
{5}
```

I was expecting to see something like {2,3,4,5,6}.

I thought this might be Union running within Intersection but...

```
Union[{2,3,4,5,6},SameTest->(Abs[#1-#2]<=1&)]
```

gives...

```
{2,4,6}
```

So I am at something of a loss.

## Part II

Given the comments below, clearly Intersection isn't going to give me what I want, which is

1. every element from list a that is within some given distance of any element within list b.
   and
2. every element from list b that is within some given distance of any element within list a.

I can do this with something ugly like...

```
Union[Flatten[Select[Apply[Join, Outer[List, a, b]], Abs[{1, -1}.#] <= 1 &]]]
```

But the Outer is likely to bite hard with big lists.

Any improvements spring to mind?

Comment: In your first example, there is a typo, you use `#1` in both cases. In general, your sameness function is not transitive (meaning that from `a ~ b` and `b ~ c` does not follow `a ~ c` in general, where I used `~` to denote sameness function), so you may expect different results depending on the order in which things are compared. So, you should either use a transitive sameness function, or rely on a particular order of comparisons, if you want predictable and deterministic results.

Comment: To add to what @Leonid Shifrin noted about the typo, once you have one element, all others will be deemed "SameQ". Hence that singleton result.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - Thank you, that does make sense.  I suppose the next question is... how do I get what I actually want?

Comment: @Ymareth Well, the first step would be to clearly formulate what you actually want. It is clear that for non-transitive sameness function, the result will depend on the order of the elements in your lists. OTOH, functions like `Complement`, `Intersection`, `Union` etc. treat lists as sets. Which means that they are probably inappropriate for your needs, unless you manage to reformulate your problem to use a transitive sameness function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing **Part II** here is a fairly efficient method using [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html) and [`IntervalMemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html):

```
distanceInt[a_, b_, d_: 1] :=
  Module[{toInt, pick},
    toInt = Interval @@ ({# - d, # + d}\[Transpose]) &;
    pick = Pick[#, toInt[#2] ~IntervalMemberQ~ #] &;
    pick[a, b] ⋃ pick[b, a]
  ]
```

A single timing compared to your method:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{a, b} = List @@ RandomInteger[99999, {2, 1000}];

Union[Flatten[Select[Apply[Join, Outer[List, a, b]], Abs[{1, -1}.#] <= 1 &]]] // 
 Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.623093, 50}
> ```

```
distanceInt[a, b, 1] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.003000, 50}
> ```

Comment: Ideal, thank you.

Comment: @Ymareth You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When lists are like these.

```
a = {1, 4, 6, 11, 12}; b = {0, 1, 5, 10};
```

My try is this.

```
f[p_, q_, n_: 1] := Table[Intersection[p + i, q], {i, -n, n}]
{f[a, b], f[b, a]} // Flatten // Union
```

> `{0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11}`

**Timing**

```
distanceInt[a, b, 1] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.015600, 50}`

```
{f[a, b], f[b, a]} // Flatten // Union // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0., 50}`

Comment: Nice idea, but I think that the integer lists were only an example in which case this enumeration will not be robust.  Even for integers the operation will slow as `n` grows.  Consider e.g. `{a, b} = List @@ RandomInteger[1*^7, {2, 1000}];` and then `distanceInt[a, b, 2500]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You right. It is just show that my code is not much slow.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Just I tried with simple code.:)

Comment: And for the example the OP gave it works just fine.  Sorry for being overly critical.  Sometimes I focus too much on my own assumptions about the nature of the question.

Comment: FYI - The actual use case concerns lists of times (represented by "HH:MM:SS.sss" strings, Mathematica's TimeObjects being woefully slow as yet) where I'm looking for nearly simultaneous events.  I convert these to Reals using {3600, 60, 1}.ToExpression[StringSplit[#, ":"]]&.  This is a lot faster than using DateDifference.