# DeleteCases vs. DeleteDuplicates for removing points within a critical Euclidean distance

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation

I'm attempting to remove all points in an array which are within a Euclidean distance "ThresDist" of one-another.  Using the command:

```
DeleteDuplicates[List, EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] <= ThresDist &];
```

I can remove one point in a pair of points that fall within a distance "ThresDist" of one-another.  However:

```
DeleteCases[List, EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] <= ThresDist  &];
```

Fails to work similarly.  Is there something wrong with my approach?

Note : I made a typo earlier in writing DeleteCases, and also used a poor variable name.  This was sloppy of me.

As for the actual question - how might I best accomplish my goal?  I've searched through Mathematica's function directory, and I can't seem to find an appropriate way to prune not just a duplicate point, but all points that fall within a threshold distance of one-another?

Comment: `DeleteDCases` is spelt incorrectly but assuming this is a typo. For `DeleteCases` you need to use a pattern and you will be parsing one argument to a function used as a pattern test or to a pattern condition

Comment: I just updated my answer with relevant links; please read those and let us know if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be new around here so I am going to answer this, but others may close it as "a simple mistake."

- `D` is a reserved (System) Symbol; use `d` or `dist` etc. instead.
- `DeleteDCases` should be `DeleteCases`.
- [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteCases.html) looks at each element independently, not pairs of elements as does [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) (when using a custom equivalence function).
- `DeleteCases` requires a pattern, not a function, for the second argument.

Since you are making a number of mistakes I shall direct you to this massive omnibus collection of instructional resources:

[Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/121)

---

In response to your updated question, specifically:

> As for the actual question - how might I best accomplish my goal?

Please see:

- [DeleteDuplicates[] does not work as expected on floating point values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21711/deleteduplicates-does-not-work-as-expected-on-floating-point-values)
- [How to remove duplicates from set of machine precision 2D points?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-set-of-machine-precision-2d-points)
- [Intersection for lists of numeric data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28695/intersection-for-lists-of-numeric-data/28696#28696)

Also related:

- [Fastest way to calculate matrix of pairwise distances](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21861/121)

Comment: I changed the actual variable name when I wrote this question to simplify things, and I have now fixed the problem.  There was a typo for DeleteCases, and that has been fixed.

Comment: @Intemediocre Okay.  I believe the other points still apply; I hope you find them helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's very helpful to know that DeleteCases and DeleteDuplicates don't work in the same manner!

Comment: Personally, I find these types of questions and answers beneficial to newcomers, so long as there are sufficient keywords to provide positive search results for future newcomers.

Comment: @bobthechemist I have no problem with these myself, so long as they are not frequent or persisting, but I am trying to respect community opinion as well.  I only meant to warn the user that such questions might be closed by those who feel that they are too basic.