# Comparison of Dispatch objects ureliable in Mathematica 10

Tags: symbolic

In 2008 I wrote a group theory package. I've recently started using it again, and I found that one (at least) of my functions is broken in Mathematica 10. The problem is complicated to describe, but the essence of it occurs in this line:

```
l = Split[l, Union[#1] == Union[#2] &]
```

Here `l` is a list of sets. The intent of the line is to split `l` into sublists of identical sets. Each set is represented as a list of group elements. I say "sets" rather than "lists" because two sets are to be considered identical if they contain the same members in any order. This is the reason for comparing `Union`s of the sets.

This used to work, but now it doesn't. The problem is that sets that, as far as I can tell, are equal, do not compare equal by this test. fact, the comparison `e1 == e2` for indistinguishable group elements `e1` and `e2` also sometimes fails to yield `True`. (It remains unevaluated; `e1 === e2` evaluates to `False`.) The elements can be fairly complicated objects. For instance, in one case where I'm having this problem, `ByteCount[e1]` is 2448. But `e1` and `e2` are indistinguishable. For instance,  `ToString[FullForm[e1]] === ToString[FullForm[e2]]` yields `True`.

I've shown one line where this failure to compare equal causes a problem. In this one case I could probably work around the problem by defining `UpValue`s for `e1 == e2` or `e1 === e2`. But, unfortunately, the problem raises its head in other contexts as well. For instance, I am trying to use `GraphPlot` to show a cycle graph of the elements. `GraphPlot` takes a list of edges of the form `ei->ej`. In order to recognize that edges `ei->ej` and `ei->ek` are both connected to `ei`, `GraphPlot` needs to know that the `ei` appearing in the first edge is the same as `ei` in the second. It doesn't, so I get a disconnected graph. Unlike `Split`, `GraphPlot` doesn't provide a hook to enable me to tell it how to test vertexes for equality, and it apparently doesn't use `Equal` or `SameQ`, either, as `UpValue`s I define for those are not used.

(Sorry about the generic tag -- I couldn't find anything more specific. Suggestions welcome.)

EDIT: In response to Szabolcs request, here is the `FullForm` of such an object:

```
a = sdp[znz[1, 3], 
 aut[List[Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]]], 
  List[Rule[znz[0, 3], znz[0, 3]], Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]], 
   Rule[znz[2, 3], znz[2, 3]]], 
  Dispatch[List[Rule[znz[0, 3], znz[0, 3]], 
    Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]], Rule[znz[2, 3], znz[2, 3]]]]], 
 Function[NonCommutativeMultiply[Slot[2], Slot[1]]]]

b = sdp[znz[1, 3], 
 aut[List[Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]]], 
  List[Rule[znz[0, 3], znz[0, 3]], Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]], 
   Rule[znz[2, 3], znz[2, 3]]], 
  Dispatch[List[Rule[znz[0, 3], znz[0, 3]], 
    Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]], Rule[znz[2, 3], znz[2, 3]]]]], 
 Function[NonCommutativeMultiply[Slot[2], Slot[1]]]]

a === b

(* ==> False *)
```

Note that `a` and `b` are identical and `ToString[a] === ToString[b]` gives `True`.

Comment: What version did you write it in?

Comment: Not sure--whatever was current in 2008. 6, maybe.

Comment: `==` is not really an appropriate way of testing whether expressions are the same.  It's meant to be used to represent mathematical equality between algebraic expressions.  This is why `a==b` won't evaluate to `True` or `False`.  According to Mathematica, `a` and `b` stand for (complex) numbers here and whether they're equal depends on what is `a` and `b`.  I think in your case `===` is the way to go.

Comment: I have tried both. Neither works.

Comment: Can you give examples of objects that don't compare as equal by GraphPlot?  Perhaps put them in a pastebin, since they're large.

Comment: Do you have any inexact numbers in your expression?  An inexact number is anything that has a decimal point in it.  `1.` is inexact while `1` is exact.  [This is why I'm asking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22082/12)

Comment: No inexact numbers. What is a pastebin?

Comment: A pastebin is a website for temporarily sharing text (code, datafiles, etc.).  Like [this one](http://pastebin.com/).  I suggested it because I thought that your expression would be huge and wouldn't fit in a post here.  But it's quite small actually, so there's no need for the pastebin.  I'll take a look at this when I have time.  First idea:  I know that `Dispatch` has been changed in Mathematica 10, so it's the first suspect.

Comment: I edited your post slightly to make it clear how to reproduce the failure of comparison.  This broke in version 10, it still works in v9.  It is very likely due to `Dispatch`.

Comment: Please see the update at the end of my answer.

Comment: This was filed as a bug report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a full answer, just a start towards a solution.

The culprit is `Dispatch`, which became [atomic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AtomQ.html) in version 10, and comparison wasn't implemented for it.

Here's a small test in version 9:

```
In[1]:= a = 
  Dispatch[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, 
    "f" -> 6, "g" -> 7, "h" -> 8, "i" -> 9, "j" -> 10, "k" -> 11, 
    "l" -> 12, "m" -> 13}];

In[2]:= b = 
  Dispatch[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, 
    "f" -> 6, "g" -> 7, "h" -> 8, "i" -> 9, "j" -> 10, "k" -> 11, 
    "l" -> 12, "m" -> 13}];

In[3]:= AtomQ[a]
Out[3]= False

In[4]:= a === b
Out[4]= True
```

(Note that there need to be a certain number of elements in the dispatch table before it actually builds a hash table from it.  It won't happen when using only a few rules.)

In version 10 we get

```
In[3]:= AtomQ[a]
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= a === b
Out[4]= False
```

Unfortunately I do not see an easy solution around this as the `Dispatch` objects are only small parts of the expressions you are comparing.  A "proper" solution would be a significant reworking of the package, but who has time for that ... ?

Another question is: is this a bug?  I suspect that many *programmers* (which most of us aren't) wouldn't consider it a bug.  There was good reason to make `Dispatch` atomic, for good performance, and seamlessly integrating atomic objects into Mathematica is hard.  Lots of operations need special implementation for a seamless integration: pattern matching, comparison, translation to/from some sort of FullForm, etc.  Also, the type of comparison you are doing between these expressions could be considered a hack or a quick-and-dirty solution.

On the other hand: Mathematica has always had the implicit promise that we can rely on [everything being an expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html) and one of its big strengths is that it's really easy to hack together useful and working solutions.  They are often not proper solutions, but most people who use Mathematica (researchers) don't *develop software*, as programmers do.  We just create quick and dirty solutions for our own immediate use, targeted at the problem at hand.  And Mathematica really shines at this.

You should definitely contact WRI about this and let them know about your use case.

---

### Possible workaround

Here's a possible workaround: instead of `Dispatch`, use `Association` (new in 10).  In a quick test, `Association` seems to give similar performance benefits to `Dispatch`.  But unlike `Dispatch`, associations *can* be compared using `===`.  Just be sure to `KeySort` the association before including it in the expression:  `<| a -> 1, b -> 2 |>` is different from `<| b -> 2, a -> 1 |>`.

Comment: +1, didn't know comparison was order sensitive

Answer (score 5):

As @Szabolcs points out `Dispatch` does not interact well with `SameQ`, etc in Mathematica 10.

```
Dispatch[1 -> 2] === Dispatch[1 -> 2]
```

> False

```
Dispatch[1 -> 2] == Dispatch[1 -> 2]
```

> False

Use `Normal` to "expand" the dispatch objects and then the comparison should work.

```
Normal[Dispatch[1 -> 2]] == Normal[Dispatch[1 -> 2]]
```

> True

`Normal` works on your complete example expression:

```
Normal[sdp[znz[1, 3], 
  aut[List[Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]]], 
   List[Rule[znz[0, 3], znz[0, 3]], Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]], 
    Rule[znz[2, 3], znz[2, 3]]], 
   Dispatch[
    List[Rule[znz[0, 3], znz[0, 3]], Rule[znz[1, 3], znz[1, 3]], 
     Rule[znz[2, 3], znz[2, 3]]]]], 
  Function[NonCommutativeMultiply[Slot[2], Slot[1]]]]]
```

> sdp[znz[1, 3], 
>   aut[{znz[1, 3] -> znz[1, 3]}, {znz[0, 3] -> znz[0, 3], 
>     znz[1, 3] -> znz[1, 3], 
>     znz[2, 3] -> znz[2, 3]}, {znz[0, 3] -> znz[0, 3], 
>     znz[1, 3] -> znz[1, 3], znz[2, 3] -> znz[2, 3]}], #2 ** #1 &]

PS As the documentation for [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) states "The use of Dispatch will never affect results that are obtained", this should probably be classified as a bug.

Comment: Thanks. That at least identifies the problem. The solution is still elusive, since there is no hook (in `GraphPlot`, for instance) that would enable me to change the way objects are tested for identity.

Comment: Can you not simply apply `Normal` to your objects before using them in `GraphPlot` - see my edit? If your lists of rules are short, as in your example, there is little advantage in having them in `Dispatch`ed form in any case.

Comment: If it were only `GraphPlot`, maybe. But it's not that simple. The replacement lists can be much longer. (I wouldn't be using `Dispatch` in the first place if they were always order 3.) And operations on `Normal`ized elements may produce elements with `Dispatch` lists. Looks like I have a major rewrite ahead. Perhaps replace `Dispatch` with `Association`... It's advertised as efficient, and seems to have sane comparison behavior.

Comment: Oh well, you'll just have to decide which workaround is easiest for you to implement (or if you want to wait for a fix from Wolfram :-)  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Another possible workaround is to wrap `Dispatch` with a memoized function, so that both expressions `a` and `b` contain references to the same internal dispatch table.

i.e. define

```
mem : disp[x_] := mem = Dispatch[x]
```

then use `disp` in place of `Dispatch` in your code.

Comment: Suggestion: it might also be worth taking care of different rule orderings.

Comment: @Szabolcs, in general rule order *does* matter though. Or is it different for `Dispatch`?

Comment: You're right, it does matter.