# Why doesn't the Round function work on decimals and how to fix it or work around it

Tags: rounding

I'm trying to specify yaxis tick labels from 0 to 1.0 in steps of 0.1.
This is what I get:

```
ygrids=Range[0,1.0,0.1];
0.,0.1,0.2,0.30000000000000004,0.4,0.5,0.6000000000000001,0.7000000000000001,0.8,0.9,1.}
```

Round[ygrids,0.01] doesn't fix it. (0.001 fixes all but the 7.0000x)

This is too simple to be this hard!

Help appreciated (version 10.1)

Comment: `Round[ygrids, 1/10] // N`, `Range[0, 1, 1/10] // N`,`N@Rationalize@Range[0, 1.0, 0.1]`...

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: This needs to be marked as a duplicate, not closed as a "simple mistake."

Comment: A few links: [(2915)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2915/121),
[(5580)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5580/121),
[(14122)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14122/121),
[(14511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14511/121),
[(39126)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39126/121),
[(65298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65298/121),
[(75528)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75528/121),
[(78298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78298/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: a duplicate of a simple mistake? ;-)

Comment: @ciao It's an issue that comes up again and again, and seems to not be so simple.  It's also been addressed before, and if it was a valid question then it probably should be now, too.  And counting duplicates is the method currently in use (my proposal) for applying the `faq` tag, so this helps site organization as well.

Comment: I looked at most of those posts and the answers did not "feel good". My solution based upon the related posts was to do this: ygrids=Range[0,1.0,0.1'2] which seems like a ridiculous thing to have to do. I haven't tried the solution offered below yet as I'm adding a frame and grids, and I'd hope that they would all play nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should cut the Gordian Knot and forget about rounding.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[0., 1., .1]}]
```

[image: plot]

The lack of rounding has no visible affect on the plot.

Comment: Yes, I will give this a try next time as I like the simplicity. I hope it works on more complicated graph axis ticks as well.