# Bad Float Counts? (Length[xs] != Total@Counts[xs])

Tags: core-language

In Mma 11.3, tallying floats with `Counts` seems to fail.  (`Tally` works fine, and rounding fixes the problem.)  Is this behavior somehow expected?

```
SeedRandom[314]
xs = Nest[RandomChoice[{0.6, 1.5}] # & /@ # &, ConstantArray[100, 100], 10]
Length[xs]  (* 100 *)
Total@Counts[xs]  (* 93 *)
```

Comment: @kglr As the question states, rounding fixes the problem.  But the question remains, is this behavior expected.  (As the question states, `Tally` does not have the same problem.)

Comment: thanks @Alan. It seems to be a general problem with using floats as keys: e.g. `assoc = AssociationThread[xs -> Range[Length[xs]]]`.

Comment: The missing key from both `Counts` and `Total[AssociationThread @@ Transpose[Tally[xs]]]` is ``9.44784` ``. The fact that it's present in `Tally[xs]`, but not the association form led me to believe it's impossible to have both ``9.44784` `` and ``9.447839999999998` `` as keys in the same association... but that's not the case as they're both present with `Merge[Association[{# -> 1}] & /@ xs, Total]`.

Comment: FWIW ``Block[{$Internal`SameQTolerance = 0.55}, Total[Counts[xs]]]`` fixes this particular example.

Comment: Since nobody is claiming this is expected behavior, I am reporting it.  As far as I can tell, it is either a bug or a documentation bug. (Perhaps we shd not expect floats to work correctly as assocation keys, but then this shd be listed as a possible issue.  Or, perhaps `Counts` shd be expected to be as intelligent as `Tally`.)

Comment: @ChipHurst I get that ``9.44784` `` and ``9.447839999999998` `` are not both present in `Merge[Association[{# -> 1}] & /@ xs, Total]`, which seems to be different than what you are saying.

Comment: @MichaelE2 hmm, what OS are you on? It's weird, I'm seeing the least significant (base 10) digit as `6` instead of `8` now... `In[18]:= $OperatingSystem

Out[18]= "MacOSX"

In[19]:= Merge[Association[{# -> 1}] & /@ xs, Total] // Keys

Out[19]= {59.048999999999985, 23.6196, 922.640625, 369.05625000000003, 59.049, 147.6225, 9.44784, 369.05625, 1.5116543999999998, 23.61959999999999, 2306.6015625, 
3.7791359999999994, 9.447839999999996}`

Comment: @ChipHurst `"11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 22, 2018)"` -- I got what you're now showing.  My theory is that because ``MatchQ[9.44784`, 9.447839999999998`]`` returns `True`, they're treated as the same key.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I’ll check my other machine later to see if I can figure out where my `9.447839999999998` came from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update:*

`Counts[data]` seems to be equivalent to `AssociationThread @@ Transpose@Tally[data]`.  The OP's problem arises because in constructing an `Association`, keys are checked for uniqueness and later entries with a duplicate key replace earlier entries.  (Simple example: `Association[{1. -> 1, 1. -> 2}]`.)  Uniqueness is determined by `MatchQ`, I believe, which has problems discussed below in the original answer.  The problem with `SameQ` not strictly being an equivalence relation due nontransitivity is still an issue.  This update principally clarifies the role of forming an association: It discards entries of the `Tally` with duplicate keys, which results in an undercount.

*Original answer:*

Working with floating-point numbers is tricky.  I'd say the most important, common issue is that rounding errors lead to different but close numbers that users wish would be treated the same.  Introductory programming courses teach that comparing floats should be done with something like `Abs[x - y] < $MyTolerance`.  In *Mathematica* similar (but relative) tolerances are built into `SameQ` and `Equal`, which are controlled by the the internal system parameters [`` Internal`$SameQTolerance `` and `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica/6626748#6626748) respectively (see also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35094/4999); [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22082/4999) has similar issues as the OP).  Perhaps less well known is that `MatchQ` has a small tolerance like `SameQ` but is slightly more restrictive.  The most important difference is that `MatchQ` is transitive but `SameQ` is not.

These functions play various roles in pattern-matching and comparing numbers, and their issues affect functions like `Counts[]` when applied to floating-point data.  When constructing classes from data, as in `Counts[]`, some reflection should lead one to think that using a comparison that is an equivalence relation, and therefore transitive, would be desirable.  And if not transitive, it should be at least "locally transitive" on the actual data being used.  By "locally transitive," I mean that the relation is transitive when restricted to the data set, even if it is not transitive on all floating-point numbers.

This seems to be the problem with the OP's example:  `SameQ` is not transitive on `xs`.  I say "seems" because I cannot check the internal workings of `Counts[]`.  It's possible that `SameQ` is used to construct the keys and `MatchQ` to tally the counts.  It seems to me that `Counts[]` uses `SameQ` and `CountsBy[]` uses `MatchQ` to construct the keys, however the counting is done.  Since `SameQ` is not transitive, the order that the data is processed can make a difference.  Nevertheless, the problem can be fixed by making `SameQ` locally transitive on `xs`.

The reason this comes up in this example is that in constructing the data `xs`, the rounding drift amounts to 2 bits (2 ulp), which is one too many for `SameQ` to be locally transitive.

Here is the best fix (that fixes `SameQ` -- [Chip Hurst points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189893/bad-float-counts-lengthxs-totalcountsxs/189917#comment494773_189893) that the tolerance can be as small as `0.55`, which is close to the value of `Log10[4.] = 0.60..` that would be predicted by the observed rounding error):

```
Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = Internal`$EqualTolerance}, 
 Total@Counts[xs]]
(*  100  *)
```

Another fix is to use `MatchQ` via `CountsBy[]`:

```
Total@CountsBy[xs, # &]
(*  100  *)
```

The `CountsBy[]` association has several keys for equal numbers, but it does have the correct total.  The first solution seems better because it has one key for each cluster of equal numbers.  (It likely that in some applications one would like distinct floating-point numbers to have distinct entries; then something like `CountsBy[xs, ToString@*FullForm]` would do the trick.)

**Appendix**

Some pictures showing the properties of `SameQ` and `MatchQ` on consecutive machine-precision floats:

```
Block[{x1},
 x1 = Table[1 + n*$MachineEpsilon, {n, 0, 5}];
 {Outer[Boole@*SameQ, x1, x1] // MatrixPlot[#, PlotLabel -> SameQ] &,
   Outer[Boole@*MatchQ, x1, x1] // MatrixPlot[#, PlotLabel -> MatchQ] &} //
     GraphicsRow
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: When I have a little more time, I may reread and revise the original answer to conform with the update.

Answer (score 2):

```
Total@Counts@Chop@xs
```

> 100

```
CountsBy[xs, N]
```

[image]

```
CountsBy[xs, N] // Total
```

> 100

Maybe the precision caused the problem during counting.

```
keys = Keys@Counts[xs];
res = xs /. Thread[keys -> ConstantArray[0, Length@keys]]//FullForm
```

> [image]

Comment: As @ChipHurst says it's not the counting that's problematic, but the construction of the Association, where a key like 9.447839999999998 is seen as the same as the already existing key 9.44784 and thus overwrites its value, giving you a loss of data.

Comment: @Roman yes, but `CountsBy[xs, N] // Total` works.